# Detecting the users browser with the User Agent String

Tags: jquery, mobile, browser, user-agent

I want to detect the browser using the UAS however it seems that the general consensus is that it is a terrible idea. My problem is that by using say, JS or JQuery it would detect it to late, I need the server to be told what browser and send back browser specific information.

This is for a mobile part of the site, if a mobile browser is detected, the server sends content B otherwise it is content A.

I like to keep to what the community generally approves of however I can only see one method to achieve what I want, but it feels like I am breaking a rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to check this [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

> The most common reason to perform user agent sniffing is to determine
>   which type of device the browser runs on.

Comment: This is half way to what I am looking for, although the search for 'mobi' string is a little wooly, I need to keep looking to find something with support and updates thatnk you

Answer (score 1):

you could just check if the browser is on mobile using javascript:

```
var isTouch = ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement);
if(isTouch){
      // is on mobile device
} else {
      // is NOT on mobile device
}
```

or you could use a js library like Moderizer:

http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-shiv-cssclasses-teststyles-prefixes-load

using PHP you could try this:

http://mobiledetect.net/

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/  - download the script you need

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)));
header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
?>
```

Comment: ALthough this is great, because of the nature of the app, I need to know before the server responds to the server request, is there a non-client side method?

Comment: Using JSP but I see that on the site that is an option, I shall have a read and a play. Thank you Papa!

Answer (score 0):

The server cannot know what you are using to access it by itself; a javascript library would work best for this purpose.

My solution:

Load page A which detects the browser (Modernizr works for this) then use a javascript redirect to page B with posted variables of what browser is being used.

Comment: Because of the nature of this product I really need a non-client side solution. Any ideas. Thank you for the response